# Weka - Local Outlier Factor not activated in the classifer option

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, data-science, weka, unsupervised-learning

I'm trying to detect outliers using a no code platform called Weka. I've installed the packages maintained by Weka within it's package manager. However, I've imported the KD-CUP 1999 dataset into Weka and I'm trying to use the classifer option (The Classify tab is for training and evaluating the performance of different machine learning algorithms) The issue is that the Local Outlier Factor algorithm is not activated  or simply isn't allowing me to use it depsite me installing via Weka package manager, an image is provided for better insight: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FLTr.png

Answer (score 0):

When an algorithm is *grayed out* in Weka, that means that there is a discrepancy between the type of data (i.e., attributes types) that you loaded and what the algorithm, e.g., classifier or clusterer, can handle.

Check the *Capabilities* of the classifier in the user interface (*choose* the classifier, then left-click on the field listing the name/options and then click the *Capabilities* button).

It is possible that you may have to convert some attributes in your dataset with filters (e.g., [StringToNominal](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/StringToNominal.html) or [NumericToNominal](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/NumericToNominal.html)) before you can use that particular classifier.

Comment: Thank you for this, even when I used the filter 'StringToNominal' (it contains attributes) It still doesn't allow me to use the LOF. I then decided to apply the InputMappedClassifier on the classifier option (to address any incompatibilities with the dataset) that didn't work too.

Comment: I've also tried the 'NumericToNominal' filter (within the preprocessing section) it still doesn't allow me to the apply the LOF despite the fact it converts these attributes within the dataset.

Comment: Did you check the capabilities of LOF and compared them against your dataset?

Comment: I have checked the capabilities of the LOF and my dataset should work after applying the fliters. The dataset contains network packet data (KDD-CUP 1999). However, you did say to apply the filters which I did but then again it maybe different to one's you've suggested.

Comment: I am new to this so I do apologise. So I assume I have to apply a filter based on the given capablities of the LOF to avoid discrepancy but then again I've tried the two filters you've suggested, not really sure here.  The capabilities of the LOF outlines 
this:                                                                                                                               
Class -- Binary class, Missing class values, Unary class

Attributes -- Binary attributes, Empty nominal attributes, Missing values, Nominal attributes, Numeric attributes, Unary attributes

Comment: The issue is that when I do compare the capabilities of the LOF, I fail to identifity which specific filter to apply on my data from the preprocessing section as there are plenty of them (unsupervised section) but I do know you only choose the one the LOF is capable of handling

Comment: Based on the capabilities that you posted, you have to ensure that your dataset has a binary class (ie a nominal class attribute with only two labels) and only numeric or binary attributes. If you have multi-valued nominal attributes, you will need to apply the [NominalToBinary](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/NominalToBinary.html) filter.

Comment: I totally get what you mean because my dataset can be considered containing multi valued nominal attributes (IP_src , IP_dst, etc) . Even when I do apply the NominalToBinary that filter that doesn't work either (preprocessing section, unsupervised category). I understand why you chose the filter it makes perfect sense to me  but I just don't understand why it's still not letting me parse the dataset through the LOF, the filter completely fits with the context of my dataset :/

Comment: Not all filters modify the class attribute when present. Since I'm not familiar with your dataset make sure that ALL your attributes comply with the LOF capabilities.

Comment: duration  protocol_type  service flag src_bytes dst_bytes
0 tcp http SF 181 5450
0 tcp http SF 239 486
0 tcp http SF 235 1337
0 tcp http SF 219 1337
0 tcp http SF 217 2032
0 tcp http SF 217 2032

Comment: BTW The Weka Investigator (part of [ADAMS](https://adams.cms.waikato.ac.nz/)), which is a more powerful version of the Weka Explorer, either shows a hint on the *Start* buttons or an error dialog when trying to apply a classifier/clusterer/filter/etc to a dataset that it can't handle. Try using the [adams-ml-app snapshot](https://adams.cms.waikato.ac.nz/download/snapshot/).

Comment: The above is the structure of my dataset, Imagine this in this in a excel spreadsheet duration 0,   protocol tcp,  service http. I'm really sure that the NominalToBinary is applied in this instance as the structure of the data is labeled because the capabilities of the LOF is capeable of handling binary attributes. But then again there are no other filters seem applicable anymore if just disregard some of the filters I've and you've mentioned.

Comment: But is your class attribute binary (check the Preprocess panel after you have loaded it into Weka)? Remember, LOF only works with binary classes!

Comment: Just to share some thought, the LOF algorithm also appears within the preprocessing category too within the unsupervised catergory as a filter but not avaliable in the classifer section after applying the NominalToBinary filter. Do you think that could work  and also would still have to apply the NominalToBinary and then also LOF filter that's avaliable within the unsupervised learning category ? I had just applied this the LOF, it took like 10 hours to process, makes me sick to even think about that momment.

Comment: Update: I've find a dataset with binary attributes alongside nominal data. Hopefully, this should work now